# Determine Total Margin Between Two Elements

Tags: html, css

On my web development quiz I got this question wrong and was wondering if anyone could explain why 10 is the correct answer?

[Margin Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTmpd.png)

Wouldn't the distance be 15px because there is a 10px margin-bottom distance on element one, and a 5px margin-top distance for element two.

10px+5px=15px

I don't really get why it's 10px.

I tried answering 15px but that was listed as incorrect.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Answer (score 0):

yes, `10px` is the correct answer, as the question already say's both elements' margins will overlap(Collapse) with each other, and when two different size margins collapse the bigger margin will win.

[This](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/rules-of-margin-collapse/) article has a really good explanation of collapsing margins.

[Mozilla doc's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing#examples)

Answer (score 0):

Harvey,

If you reread the question carefully it gives you a hint.  It says the margins overlap.  when two divs have margins the smaller margin is overlapped by the larger margin.  Try it.

notice below how the spacing is the same

```css
.large {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#small {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="large">
  abc
</div>
<div id='small'>
  xyz
</div>

<div class="large">
  abc
</div>
<div id='small2'>
  xyz
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known as **margin collapse** and only occurs on vertical (top and bottom) margins.
The margins of two elements are equal to their largest and the smaller margins overlap the larger one.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what logic might suggest, CSS actually doesn't add up margins, but instead it overlaps them (picks the bigger one). In your case, the two neighboring elements had margins of 10px and 5px, hence 10px was picked, and this is why the margin between the two elements is 10px, not 15px.